# Why this animation occurs in this web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to understand why this menu animation occurs when I hoovering a navigation item on this web page.
(hoovering over "Dashboards" or any other main navigation item opens the submenu)

[Demo](https://coderthemes.com/ubold/layouts/dark-horizontal/index.html#)

**What I've tried so far #1:**

Using Chrome debugger tools I discovered the following lines in app.min.js (previously I formatted with {}):

```
   $('.navigation-menu li.has-submenu a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() < 992) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('open').find('.submenu:first').toggleClass('open');
        }
    });
```

I set a breakpoint there, the handler is called only when literally clicking, (not on hoover) and btw has no effect. So something else is running on hoover (this is according that the handler is installed in `click`)

**What I've tried so far #2:**

Search for `navigation-menu` or `has-submenu` classes in the source: No other usages found

**What I've tried so far #3:**

Tried to set Event Listener Breakpoint in Chrome in many things including mouse or animation, neither is activated when I hoovered on the "Dashboards" or any other main navigation items but the submenu opened.

**Question**

How this submenu open/close is implemented?

Comment: You're chaining toggleClass two times.

Comment: Thx, that may explain why the click handler does nothing, but my question is why it is working on hoover?

Comment: not sure; somewhere implemented in css? Searcing may not work as css could be defined in li element than on its class. So I suggest you to inspect them manually.

Comment: @g.pickardou I misunderstood, hence i deleted the comment a min after. Which animation are we talking about tbh? I'm looking at your demo link and can't figure out which one you mean. If it's the menu opening, that's going to be a :hover event in CSS but that should not activate the button on click unless they both just do the same thing.

Comment: @Shilly: hoovering over "Dashboards" main menu item or any other main navigation item (like Apps) opens the submenu

Comment: That should be CSS code and should have nothing to do with the button click code. Let's look at the source CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS stylesheet `app.min.css` contains a couple of the following rules for various screensizes:

```
.navigation-menu>li.has-submenu:hover>.submenu{
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  margin-top:0
}
```

One of those should be responsible for 'opening the submenu', which technically is 'making it visible', since the menu is always there, just transparent/invisible/not in the correct position.

Comment: Many thanks, (I do not have deeper CSS just examined the JS). This explains the visibility toggle. Is there the animation kinde (fade in) defined also in CSS?

Comment: Maybe. It'll either be a CSS animation, but it's also very likely that's a JQuery animation, sicne they were more popular than pure CSS animations due to crossbrowser things: JQuery.animate() in the JS. If you can't find it in the JS, it's probably CSS, in which case there should be either a `keyframe` rule OR `transformation: x;` rules you can look for.